# Build ROS nodes with Bazel

Tags: build, ros, bazel

Is it possible to Build ROS nodes with Bazel? 
e.g. could we build below example with Bazel? 
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29

Please share your views and solution if possible.

Comment: Is ROS a standalone OS or a framework? If the latter, what OS are you building on? Have you tried building the ROS example using Bazel, and if so, how far did you get?

Comment: ROS is a framework and i have installed it on Ubuntu.
Yes i tried it and it worked for me after alot of research.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to share what steps you had to take?

Comment: @László yes I would share it soon. You may ask a specific question please here(in case its urgent), I shall try to answer.

PS: I am also new to bazel, still learning..!!

Comment: [@Manan Maqbool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678041/user-name-in-bazelrc/47692113#47692113): cool thanks! Nothing urgent, I just want to have the answer here so we can reference it in the future. It'd be great if you submitted it as an answer, not a comment, so the questions shows up as answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bazel. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nicolò Valigi has done so on a GitHub repository: 
https://github.com/nicolov/ros-bazel

His steps are:

1. Use Catkin from within Bazel to build base ROS code.
2. Run message generation as Skylark rules.

This works for C++ and Python code.