# User name in .bazelrc

Tags: bazel, bazelrc

I would like to add this to my `.bazelrc`, but the `$(whoami)` doesn't expand like if it was in a shell.

```
startup --output_user_root=/tmp/bazel/out/$(whoami)
```

It produces the literal result:

```
/tmp/bazel/out/$(whoami)/faedb999bdce730c9c495251de1ca1a4/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/
```

Is there any way to do what I want: adding a name/hash to the option in the .bashrc file?

*Edit: what I really want is to set the outputRoot to /tmp/bazel/out without using an environment variable and to let bazel create it's user and workspace hash directories there.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Bazel from a wrapper script. In fact, that's exactly what the `bazel` binary is (at least on Linux): it's a wrapper script that calls `bazel-real`. You can edit this wrapper script if you like, or rename it to `bazel.sh` and write your own wrapper.

Comment: Since there is no supported proper way of solving this (see. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4248) I'm accepting your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/bazel` is a script which looks for `//tools/bazel`, and if it exists, calls it.  Otherwise, it calls `bazel-real`.  This lets you check Bazel into your repo, or otherwise modify how it gets called.  We use that to download a specific version of bazel, extract it, and then call it.

I would recommend creating `//tools/bazel`, and having that do your modification.  It can then either call a versioned version of bazel, or call `bazel-real`.  That keeps your modifications local to your repo rather than global.

Comment: do you have your `tools/bazel` script available anywhere? That would be useful